# Tower of Hanoi list of disks on the rods

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, homework

I'm currently trying to finish a program that outputs the "radius" of each disk on each rod in lists. I currently wrote this program:

```
k = 3
ct = 0
list1 = Table[n, {n, 1, k}];
list2 = {};
list3 = {};
solveHanoi[n_, start_, aux_, end_] := Module[{},

   If[n == 1,
      ct++;
   first = First[ToExpression["list" <> start]];
   rest = Rest[ToExpression["list" <> start]];
   list = ToExpression["list" <> end];
   list = AppendTo[list, first];
   Clear[Evaluate["list" <> end], Evaluate["list" <> start]];
   Evaluate[Symbol["list" <> start]] = rest;
   Evaluate[Symbol["list" <> end]] = list;
   Print[Column[{ToExpression["list" <> start], 
      ToExpression["list" <> aux], ToExpression["list" <> end]}]]
     ,
      solveHanoi[n - 1, start, end, aux];
      ct++;
   first = First[ToExpression["list" <> start]];
   rest = Rest[ToExpression["list" <> start]];
   list = ToExpression["list" <> end];
   list = AppendTo[list, first];
   Clear[Evaluate["list" <> end], Evaluate["list" <> start]];
   Evaluate[Symbol["list" <> start]] = rest;
   Evaluate[Symbol["list" <> end]] = list;
   Print[Column[{ToExpression["list" <> start], 
      ToExpression["list" <> aux], ToExpression["list" <> end]}]];
      solveHanoi[n - 1, aux, start, end]
      ]
    ]

solveHanoi[3, "1", "2", "3"]
```

For some reason the output starts messing up once the second and the third stack starts swapping, as it seems to mistaken between them. I tried looking for solutions but I don't know what I did wrong.

This is the base program our teacher gave us:

```
solveHanoi[n_, start_, aux_, end_] := Module[{},
    If[n == 1,
      ct++;
      Print[
    "Step " <> ToString[ct] <> " : Move from " <> start <> " to " <> 
     end],
      solveHanoi[n - 1, start, end, aux];
      ct++;
      Print[
    "Step " <> ToString[ct] <> " : Move from " <> start <> " to " <> 
     end];
      solveHanoi[n - 1, aux, start, end]
      ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huh, all these statements with `Evaluate` have the tendency to mess up things. What you try to realize there is called [call by reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference): The strings that you supply as arguments to `solveHanoi` work as [pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) to the respective arrays. Indeed, this is pretty clever, but you can do that *much* cleaner by assigning `solveHanoi` the attribute `HoldAll` and by calling `solveHanoi` directly with the lists as arguments; this way, the arguments can be manipulated by side effects within the function body (see the code below). In general, this is a very efficient strategy but it is also somewhat undesired in the Mathematica language, mostly because it confuses users. Nonetheless, we are going to employ it.

The second thing that I observed is that you probably want to `Prepend` or `PrependTo` instead of `AppendTo`. By the way: `PrependTo` and `AppendTo` have the attribute `HoldFirst`, which is like `HoldAll` but for the first argument only. So, the effect of `list = AppendTo[list,first]` is also achieved by `AppendTo[list,first]`.

But the very simple issue that might got you puzzled is that you print the towers always in the order `start`, `aux`, `end`; note that the actual towers that are pointed to by these "pointers" vary in each call to `solveHanoi`. It might be better to print the towers in fixed order: `Print[Row[{list1, list2, list3}]];`.

The cleaned-up code could look like this:

```
ClearAll[solveHanoi]
SetAttributes[solveHanoi, HoldAll]
solveHanoi[n_, start_, aux_, end_] := If[
  n == 1,
  ct++;
  PrependTo[end, First[start]];
  start = Rest[start];
  Print[Row[{list1, list2, list3}]];
  ,
  solveHanoi[n - 1, start, end, aux];
  ct++;
  PrependTo[end, First[start]];
  start = Rest[start];
  Print[Row[{list1, list2, list3}]];
  solveHanoi[n - 1, aux, start, end]
  ]
```

And this is how to call it:

```
k = 3;
ct = 0;
list1 = Table[n, {n, 1, k}];
list2 = {};
list3 = {};
solveHanoi[k, list1, list2, list3]
```

> {2,3}{}{1}
>
> {3}{2}{1}
>
> {3}{1,2}{}
>
> {}{1,2}{3}
>
> {1}{2}{3}
>
> {1}{}{2,3}
>
> {}{}{1,2,3}

So basically, you had perfectly the right idea.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew that HoldAll was a method of halting the evaluation but I didn't know the way that it can Hold the evaluation of a symbol without Holding the entire evaluation. Thanks so much.

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: @user52616. In addition to thanking Henrik, I think you should accept his answer. Just click on big check mark you see on the left of this answer. He will get 15 points and you will get 2 for being properly appreciative